# How can I scrape text (captcha) from a website?

Tags: vb.net

I was thinking of scraping the text from this [website](http://silverzone.org/newweb/ITHO17Result.html) so that I could automatically compile results of all the children who participated in an Olympiad.

Earlier, the site asked only for the enrollment number, but recently they changed their layout and have begun asking for captcha. Though, I noticed the fact that the captcha was not actually in image format.

There is just a background image, and there is randomly generated numbers overlay on it.

```
<input type="text" id="txtCaptcha" class="txtcaptcha" disabled="" style="background-image:url(images/1.jpg);text-align:center; border:none;
            font-weight:bold; font-family:Modern">
```

I was thinking of scraping the text again, but the captcha is throwing a hindrance. I know how to fill in the other text boxes but am unable to get the captcha text.

I tried this naive approach:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate(http://silverzone.org/newweb/ITHO17Result.html)
txt1.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.getElementById("txtCaptcha").InnerText
```

But txt1 just remains blank!
Any help on this matter would be highly appreciated by me!

P.S: I am just a student who was bored of entering several numbers to check other students' results. So I thought of scraping the website and compiling all the results.

Also, if possible, could anyone of you provide me with the code so that I could enter it directly into a database in MS Access or MySQL. Because currently, I am just saving all the results to a text file!

A sample enrollment no: **T16851009-01**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I hope you're not actually trying to get the captcha ***directly*** after navigating, because at that point the page has not been downloaded yet. If you are then you really need to move your code to the [**`DocumentCompleted`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Now, [**`InnerText`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.innertext(v=vs.110).aspx) gets the text *between* the `<input></input>` tags. It will always be empty because an `<input>` element doesn't have anything inside its tags. Instead they store their input in the `value` attribute, which is what you have to get instead:

```
txt1.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("txtCaptcha").GetAttribute("value")
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! It worked! I had another query! On the same page (link) enter the enrollment no as T16851009-01 and anything rubbish for the rest of them and when we get to the result page, any way to scrape data off it??

Comment: @ArnavVarshney : Either get the `InnerText` of the div with the class `career_block_White` and parse that, or try to get each element individually. This answer I wrote a couple of days ago should give you a good hint of how such things can be done: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48816114/3740093