# How can i click a button that has no id using it class in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to click the login button on https://mobile.twitter.com/login I tried using

`webbrowser1.document.getelementbyid("").InvokeMember("click")`

But this wont work because the is no id or name linked to the button. I'm using vb.net.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's not a button, it's div. You'll have to do GetElementsByTagName, itarate throught that collection, identify the correct div and try to invoke the event.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48816114/3740093

Answer (score 1):

You are clicking "Nothing" that way.

You need to point it at the element, then click.
For example :

```
webbrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input").Item(10).InvokeMember("click")
```