# Web Automation - How do I input text into a rich text box on a website (textarea) defined by a class?

Tags: vb.net, webautomation

I have been trying this for a few days and am completely stuck. If anybody could help me out I would be very grateful; Im using VB.NET.

The HTML Code:

```
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td class="chat-attachment-cell"><a href="#" id="attachment-link" class="attachment-link"></a></td> 
    <td class="chat-input-cell">

    <textarea class="chat-message-input"></textarea>

    </td> 
    <td class="chat-send-cell"><a href="#" class="chat-send-button"> alt="Send" width="66" height="66" border="0">
    </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

The text box I need to input into is this bit

```
    <textarea class="chat-message-input"></textarea>
```

Thankyou in advance for any help provided

Comment: See my answer here: Possible duplicate of [Is there a possibility to address elements on a website which have no ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48813261/is-there-a-possibility-to-address-elements-on-a-website-which-have-no-id#48816114)

Comment: The answer to your question can be found in the link "Visual Vincent" has posted above....

Comment: @Visual Vincent  I think your encyclopedia is missing the `webBrowser1.Document.All` with a search for attributes using the `OuterHtml` property (which targets the whole tag content). (And I worry about writing too much :)

Comment: @Jimi : I'm not sure what you mean... Why would you want to search for elements with certain attributes using `OuterHtml` rather than `GetAttribute()`?

Comment: @Visual Vincent  Well, when you can't pre-filter the Elements with `GetElementsByTagName()` or you have an ID, you can go to `Document.All` and use `GetElementsByName()`. When you don't have even that, you can check the `OuterHtml` value and test the whole Tag it gives back. It think is where `GetElementsByClassName()` comes from.

Comment: @Jimi : I know about `Document.All` (infact I use it in the third example), however I still don't see why one would want to check the _entire_ tag over `GetAttribute()`? To check multiple attributes use multiple `GetAttribute()` calls. Matching more than one attribute (or the entire tag) using `OuterHtml` is a bad idea since (depending on how the website works) the attributes may not always be in the same order.

Comment: @Visual Vincent  Yes, but you're calling `GetAttribute()` on a Element you have already identified or in the elements in an already filtered collection (`GetElementsByTabName()`). What If you only have the class name of the Element (no Tag name, no Id, no name)?

Comment: @Jimi : I modified the first example and noted `GetElementsByTagName()` in its description. :)

Answer (score 0):

You select the element then change the .innertext property with what you want.

There are multiple ways to do it, and I can't give you an example because I don't know what you are using nor the whole html, but for example it could look like this:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("someid").InnerText="Sometext"
```

For start, you can try looking how the collection of elements you get looks, then you should be able to figure out what to do next.

```
Dim test = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("textarea")
```

For example on this page:

```
  Dim test = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("tbody")
   test(1).InnerText = "Hi there"
```

[image]

Comment: The element is not defined by an id though, it's defined by a class.
        <textarea class="chat-message-input"></textarea>

Comment: That's what I said it could look like. We don't know what he is using/wants to use nor the whole html. if it's a webbrowser for example we could select the element using classname.

Comment: I am using an embedded webbrowser, the default one in toolbox not an additional plugin or anything

Comment: And are you using some additional library like htmlagilitypack for example?