# Click String That Runs Javascript

Tags: vb.net, parsing, click

I am trying to click a string of text within a web browser control that runs some javascript, I am unsure how to click the text as the method I use for buttons does not work in this instance

```
    Function Clk(WebBrowserID, ElementID)

    WebBrowserID.Document.GetElementById(ElementID).InvokeMember("click")
    Return "Clicked"
End Function
```

This is all that is visible to the client in regards to the clickable text

```
<div class="task-skip pure-g">
    <div class="pure-u-1">

            <a href="javascript:;" class="task-skip js-next">Next</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

I am completely lost on how to either click the text so that the javascript script runs or to invoke the script through code so the button does not need to be pressed, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You obviously can't use `GetElementById` because the element you want to get has no `id` attribute.  You need to use some other method to get the element and to distinguish it from other elements. `GetElementsByTagName` seems a good place to start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a possibility to address elements on a website which have no ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48816114)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found and worked is as below hope this will help anyone else with the issue.

```
    For Each Element As HtmlElement In Browser.Document.All
        If Element.InnerText = "TEXT HERE" Then
            Element.InvokeMember("click")
        End If
    Next

    Return "RETURN VALUE"
```