# Get value inside HTML tag - Need text inside <div class> tag

Tags: html, vb.net, extract

I'm trying to extract the Total Revenue value from my online CRM.

Here's the snippet of the page source I'm targeting:

```
<div class="col-md-6 clear">
    <label class="compact">Total Revenue</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    369.0
</div>
```

Getting data from text fields and seeing if data exists in a website's source is no issue but the roadblock I'm having is trying to get this value above.

Some extra info, this segment of HTML will always look the same except for the value.

What would be the best way to extract that "369.0" value to a string?

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried first.  There's lots of information around about screen-scraping so do your research, do what you think is required and then, if you still have issues, post all the information relevant to that.

Comment: We need a little more info. Are you using asp.net? Is the HTML in a browser instance in a .net application? Are you interpreting the string as returned from an API or via pagescraping?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a possibility to address elements on a website which have no ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48813261/is-there-a-possibility-to-address-elements-on-a-website-which-have-no-id)

Comment: You didn't specify what you are using to get the data and what you are using to extract it.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can do something like the following: However, depending on the rest of your code, a different solution might be worth investigating.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var result = $(".col-md-6.clear").next().text();
 $("#result").text(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6 clear">
    <label class="compact">Total Revenue</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    369.0
</div>
<div id="result" style="background-color: salmon;">
</div>
```