# Webbrowser 2 similar buttons how to click only 1?

Tags: vb.net, button, automation, webbrowser-control

I'm doing an automation bot for my website using vb.net
I'm facing a problem with button click I have these 2 buttons

Button 1

```
<button type="submit" id="import_btn" class="btn btn-primary w-sm waves-effect waves-light"> Fetch </button>
```

button 2

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect"> <span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span>CREATE </button>
```

for automation I'm using this code:

```
For Each elem2 As HtmlElement In Webbrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
            Dim valueArrtibute As String = elem2.GetAttribute("type")
            If valueArrtibute = "submit" Then
                elem2.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        Next
```

I want to click button 2 but with my code is clicking both clicks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a check for the button's [`InnerText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.innertext?view=netframework-4.7.2), which represents all text between the button's start and end tag (`<button>` and `</button>`).

```
If valueArrtibute = "submit" AndAlso elem2.InnerText.Contains("CREATE") Then
```

There are many ways to identify a specific element on a website. For more in-depth examples I recommend seeing my answer to this question: [Is there a possibility to address elements on a website which have no ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48816114/3740093)