# GetElementById, but I can't find the ID in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, getelementbyid, basic

I was trying to use getelementbyid on vb.net, but I can't find the ID, can you help me? The button code is this below:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button" onclick="start()"
```

What code do I use to press the desired button?

Comment: Not every element has an Id and those that don't can't be accessed using `GetElementById`. You'll need to use some other method, like getting it by class and index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a possibility to address elements on a website which have no ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48816114/3740093)

Comment: There is no id, use the class instead.

Comment: how can i use the class? I'm new to vb.net and I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Everything is explained in the duplicate I suggested, with examples. Please check it out.